# ¿Como hago un duplicado de los registros de una tabla, modificando los datos de una columna?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Explico:**

Tengo una tabla **partes** con los campos **id, nombre, id_padre, id_equipos, status**.

Capturo los datos de las partes del equipo que deseo copiar:

```
$datos_partes = Partes::select(array('nombre', 'id_equipos', 'id_padre', 'status'))
->where('id_equipos', '=', $req->id)
->get()
->toArray();
```

Recorro todos las posiciones para así editar los **id_equipos** y asignarles el nuevo que tendrán, uno a uno los voy registrando en la **db**.

```
foreach($datos_partes as $clave => $elemento){
    $datos_partes[$clave]['id_equipos'] = $result['id'];
    Partes::create($datos_partes[$clave]);
}
```

Hace los registros correctamente, el problema que tengo es que  los **id_padre** no se como modificarlos y actualizarlos a los nuevos **id** que existen.

**Resultado de lo que hago actualmente:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mi solución fue la siguiente:** *esta comentado paso a paso*

```
$id_equipo_old = $req->id; //id del equipo que traigo de la vista para copiar
$id_equipo_new = $result['id']; //id del equipo ya copiado

//obtengo todas las partes que pertenecen al registro anterior
$datos_partes_viejos = Partes::select(array('nombre', 'id_equipos', 'id_padre', 'status'))
->where('id_equipos', '=', $id_equipo_old)
->get()
->toArray();

//hago un recorrido de los registros y los vuelvo a registrar pero con el "id_equipos" nuevo
foreach($datos_partes_viejos as $clave => $elemento){
    $datos_partes_viejos[$clave]['id_equipos'] = $id_equipo_new;
    Partes::create($datos_partes_viejos[$clave]);
}

//obtengo las partes nuevas registradas 
$datos_partes_nuevos = Partes::select(array('id', 'nombre', 'id_padre'))
->where('id_equipos', '=', $id_equipo_new)
->get()
->toArray();

//creo una variable para almacenar los registros q se editaran
$ids = [];

//ahora recorro todos los registros nuevos
foreach($datos_partes_nuevos as $clave => $elemento){
    //entro en el registro si el "id_padre" es diferente de 0, puesto que los "id_padre" = 0 son copiados tal cual y no representan ningun error
    if($datos_partes_nuevos[$clave]['id_padre'] !== 0){

        //realizo una consulta y a cada registro busco los datos del "id_padre"
        $datos_partes_original = Partes::select(array('nombre', 'id_padre'))
        ->where('id', '=', $datos_partes_nuevos[$clave]['id_padre'])
        ->get()
        ->first()
        ->toArray();

        //relizo otra consulta en la cual buscare el nuevo "id" en el nuevo "equipo", ¿Como?
        //coloco la condicion del "nombre" y el "id_padre" de los datos originales
        //mas el "id" del equipo nuevo
        $datos_partes_obtenida = Partes::select(array('id'))
        ->where('nombre', '=', $datos_partes_original['nombre'])
        ->where('id_padre', '=', $datos_partes_original['id_padre'])
        ->where('id_equipos', '=', $id_equipo_new)
        ->get()
        ->first()
        ->toArray();

        //creo el array con el "id" el cual se va a modificar y su respectivo "id_padre"
        $array = array(
            'id' => $datos_partes_nuevos[$clave]['id'],
            'id_padre' => $datos_partes_obtenida['id'],
        );

        //agrego el arreglo a la variable "$ids"
        array_push($ids, $array);
    }
}

//recorro lo que contiene la variable "$ids" y modifico el "id_padre"
foreach($ids as $clave => $elemento){
    $id = $ids[$clave]['id'];
    $result_edit = Partes::findOrFail($id);
    $campos_edit = [
        'id_padre' => $ids[$clave]['id_padre'],
    ];
    $result_edit->update($campos_edit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente creo que es un proceso muy manual lo que intentas hacer y hasta me pregunto (sin conocer los detalles del proyecto) si podría haber sido diseñada de otra forma la estructura de la base de datos, en todo caso Laravel no ofrece alguna forma directa para regenerar estas relaciones al copiar.

Una manera distinta y un poco más "Laravel" de copiar los modelos sería con el método `replicate()`, y con `dissociate()` y `associate()` para unirlo al nuevo equipo, se me ocurre algo así (sin probar):

```
$datos_partes = Partes::select(array('nombre', 'id_equipos', 'id_padre', 'status'))
    ->where('id_equipos', '=', $req->id)
    ->get();

foreach($datos_partes as $parte) {
    $nuevaParte = $parte->replicate();

    // $result en este caso contiene el modelo de Equipo
    // asumo que la relación se llama equipo
    $nuevaParte->equipo()->associate($result);

    $nuevaParte->push();
}
```

Hasta ahí lo que estás haciendo actualmente, en cuanto a reasociarlo al nuevo "padre", buscaría como generar un arreglo temporal donde "mapee" los padres antiguos y los nuevos:

```
$nuevosIds = [];

foreach ($datos_partes as $parte) {
    $nuevaParte = $parte->replicate();

    $nuevaParte->equipo()->associate($result);

    $nuevaParte->save();

    // pueden haber errores aquí, pero entiendes la idea
    $nuevosIds[$parte->id] = $nuevaParte->id;

    if (isset($nuevosIds[$nuevaParte->id_padre])) {

        // reasociar al modelo correspondiente
        $nuevoPadre = Partes::find($nuevosIds[$nuevaParte->id_padre]);

        // asumiendo que la relación con si mismo se llame padre
        $nuevaParte->padre()->associate($nuevoPadre);
        $nuevaParte->save();

        // si lo anterior no funciona lo puedes hacer manual
        // $nuevaParte->id_padre = $nuevosIds[$nuevaParte->id_padre];
    }
}
```

Comment: ***podría haber sido diseñada de otra forma la estructura de la base de datos*** ¿Que propones? De la manera como lo tengo funciona perfecto lo que necesito el problema es al intentar duplicar. Voy a intentar lo que dices a ver como funciona.

Comment: `replicate()` me lanza el siguiente error: ***Call to a member function replicate() on array***

Comment: Úsalo en el objeto, no en el array generado después.

Comment: Efectivamente, ya no me da error en esa linea. ¿Cual es la razón de colocar `equipo()` en `associate($nuevoPadre)`?

Comment: Con esa sintaxis estás asignando un elemento a la relación equipo, la cual asumo que está definida en tu modelo, mira la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: Cheka mi solucion